# Mysql display by date grouping

Tags: mysql

I am making a booking module for a hotel management app in mysql and I am trying to do the following:

Let's say there is a room and it has been booked by 3 clients on these dates:

```
2012-09-01 12:00:00 Customer #1
2012-09-02 12:00:00 Customer #1
2012-09-03 12:00:00 Customer #1
2012-12-03 12:00:00 Customer #2
2013-02-01 12:00:00 Customer #3
2013-02-02 12:00:00 Customer #3
```

These are my mysql data. I am trying to make a master view based on these data:

```
2012-09-01 :: 2012-09-03 -> Customer #1
2012-12-03 :: 2012-12-03 -> Customer #2
2013-02-01 :: 2013-02-02 -> Customer #3
```

So that when the administrator clicks on the corresponding customer / date link would show only the data for that customer (taken from the first screen) as a detail view.

Is this possible? Does it need a stored procedure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
DATE(MIN(your_date_column)), DATE(MAX(your_date_column)), customer
FROM your_table
GROUP BY customer
```

Comment: This is right as long as the same customer doesn't have multiple trips. If Customer #1 comes back next March, this will show him with a booking for 6 months that overlaps the other customers.

Comment: Is there a way to detect this sequentially?